# What has a better performance in cleaning a bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I'm facing continiously this basic doubt in JSF, what do you think that would have a better performance impact to clean a bean in JSF?

a) Retrieving the bean, clearing it and then setting it back to the context

```
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

  Map<String, IFEContainer> advSSSuggestions = (Map<String,IFEContainer>) context.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "advSSSuggestions");

  advSSSuggestions.clear();

  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext().getELResolver().setValue(context.getELContext(), null, "advSSSuggestions", advSSSuggestions);
```

b) Setting directly a null value for the bean in the context

```
 context.getELContext().getELResolver().setValue(context.getELContext(), null, "advSSSuggestions", null);
```

c) Setting directly a new object for the bean in the context

```
 context.getELContext().getELResolver().setValue(context.getELContext(), null, "advSSSuggestions", new HashMap<String,IFEContainer>());
```

Comment: Setting back to the context in suggestion a) is completely unnecessary. It's not PHP or so. As to your concrete question, run a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better variant a)to clean (you dont need to use ..getElResolver().setValue(..) cause it already managed). Cause after session will be destroyed, all objects of session will be destroyed too/

b) After u will put NULL to session, previous Map object will not be destroyed at them same time, u will remove it from Map.

c) Put each time new object (if it is HashMap) is too expensive to save in session context for high-load systems.